# What equipment has been used to design this robot

Tags: robotic-arm

Look at this robot here http://www.meccanotec.com/step781b.JPG
I can see rods which have a lot of holes and planes which also have holes. This seems to be a way to create flexibility in how the things are connected together to create the final robot. Is there a name for this type of equipment, metals with holes. Where can I get it? I am aware of people using lego blocks to create robots, but am not sure about what these metal rods and plates with holes are.

Is there a free application in which I can design a mechanical structure like the one in the image and add gears and then simulate it to see how it will rotate and bend should a real robot like that be created?

What would be the quickest way to create a robot like this?

Edit: Thankyou; Frank and lanyusea. If one wants to do a simulation of the mechanical model, in others words play with the robot on the computer before actually building it (with all those gears in action), which software is most suitable for that purpose?

Comment: Check my question here http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/is-it-possible-to-make-diy-clone-of-makerbeam.

Comment: As evidenced in the url's domain name that building/erector toy is called meccano.

Answer (score 4):

Those are Erector Sets. 
http://www.erector.us/

They are AWESOME!!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erector_Set

Answer (score 2):

well, besides Erector Sets, there are several other choices

The LEGO EV3 http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/products/31313-mindstorms-ev3

and

MakeBlock http://www.makeblock.cc/

They both can achieve the same goal.